# How to reverse Map

Tags: scala

Trying to reverse Map and the output is only 2 element

`val occurrences: Map[String, Int] = arr.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`

Output: HashMap(world -> 2, Hello, -> 1, hello, -> 1, hello -> 2, and -> 1, world, -> 1)

`val reversed = for ((k,v) <- occurrences) yield (v, k)`

Output: HashMap(1 -> world,, 2 -> hello)

How did I lost the other patameters?

Comment: The keys of a map are unique. So if you just reverse the bindings duplicate keys will be lost. Maybe you want to return something like `Map[V, List[K]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @user proposal, but trying to be a little bit more efficient.

```
def invertMap[K, V](map: Map[K, V]): Map[V, List[K]] =
  map
    .view
    .groupMap(_._2)(_._1)
    .view
    .mapValues(_.toList)
    .toMap
```

The performance difference would probably be negligible so go with the one you find more readable.

Comment: @user so `groupMap` on a view returns a `Map[A, View[B]]` so the `.toList` and the `_._1` are done in a single step. Also I discourage returning _(in general using)_ **Seqs**.

Answer (score 2):

As @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez said, you can't duplicate keys in a Map, so when you try to make the values the keys, some of the entries are lost.

You can instead do this to obtain a `Map[Int, List[String]]`

```
val occurrences = Map("world" -> 2, "Hello," -> 1, "hello," -> 1, "hello" -> 2, "and" -> 1, "world," -> 1)

val x: Map[Int, List[String]] = 
  occurrences.toList
    .groupBy { case (k, v) => v }
    .view.mapValues(v => v.map(_._1))
    .toMap
```

Output:

```
Map(1 -> List(Hello,, hello,, and, world,), 2 -> List(world, hello))
```

P.S. The `.view` and `.toMap` stuff is because `mapValues` on `MapOps` is deprecated for now. There'll be a proper strict version later, though.